# ReactJs | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call') on build

Tags: reactjs, build, aws-amplify

Greatings! I'd have problems on the build part of my application. When I execute the command **npm start** the aplication works well, but the problem start when I create the building files. In order to create that files I follow this steps:

*npm run-scripts build* -> Output ok
*serve -s build* -> To create a local server to deploy de result

But when I enter in the link I recive this error:
*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'call')*

I check the line when the error happen and it's looks like a problem with Amplify. Here is my index.html (when the error happend)

```
<!doctype html\>

        GPS Monitor Dashboard
        
        
        
    
    
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
        
        
            !function(i) {
                function e(e) {
                    for (var r, t, n = e[0], o = e[1], a = e[2], u = 0, c = []; u < n.length; u++)
                        t = n[u],
                        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(l, t) && l[t] && c.push(l[t][0]),
                        l[t] = 0;
                    for (r in o)
                        Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (i[r] = o[r]);
                    for (d && d(e); c.length; )
                        c.shift()();
                    return p.push.apply(p, a || []),
                    f()
                }
                function f() {
                    for (var e, r = 0; r < p.length; r++) {
                        for (var t = p[r], n = !0, o = 1; o < t.length; o++) {
                            var a = t[o];
                            0 !== l[a] && (n = !1)
                        }
                        n && (p.splice(r--, 1),
                        e = s(s.s = t[0]))
                    }
                    return e
                }
                var t = {}
                  , l = {
                    2: 0
                }
                  , p = [];
                function s(e) {
                    if (t[e])
                        return t[e].exports;
                    var r = t[e] = {
                        i: e,
                        l: !1,
                        exports: {}
                    };
                    //The error is here ---------------------------
                    return i[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, s),
                    //--------------------------------------------
                    r.l = !0,
                    r.exports
                }
                s.e = function(o) {
                    var e = []
                      , t = l[o];
                    if (0 !== t)
                        if (t)
                            e.push(t[2]);
                        else {
                            var r = new Promise(function(e, r) {
                                t = l[o] = [e, r]
                            }
                            );
                            e.push(t[2] = r);
                            var n, a = document.createElement("script");
                            a.charset = "utf-8",
                            a.timeout = 120,
                            s.nc && a.setAttribute("nonce", s.nc),
                            a.src = s.p + "static/js/" + ({}[o] || o) + "." + {
                                0: "f2dff9bf",
                                3: "61fce618",
                                5: "c99d6869",
                                6: "c5967f27",
                                7: "21e9f985",
                                8: "0649464c",
                                9: "c58aa040",
                                10: "1bf73e85",
                                11: "26eb2067",
                                12: "85a5b8ec",
                                13: "6a2aa3be",
                                14: "9d1948e6",
                                15: "05ce6ceb",
                                16: "70396b9a",
                                17: "68714992",
                                18: "9d7e341e",
                                19: "511a2587"
                            }[o] + ".chunk.js";
                            var u = new Error;
                            n = function(e) {
                                a.onerror = a.onload = null,
                                clearTimeout(c);
                                var r = l[o];
                                if (0 !== r) {
                                    if (r) {
                                        var t = e && ("load" === e.type ? "missing" : e.type)
                                          , n = e && e.target && e.target.src;
                                        u.message = "Loading chunk " + o + " failed.\n(" + t + ": " + n + ")",
                                        u.name = "ChunkLoadError",
                                        u.type = t,
                                        u.request = n,
                                        r[1](u)
                                    }
                                    l[o] = void 0
                                }
                            }
                            ;
                            var c = setTimeout(function() {
                                n({
                                    type: "timeout",
                                    target: a
                                })
                            }, 12e4);
                            a.onerror = a.onload = n,
                            document.head.appendChild(a)
                        }
                    return Promise.all(e)
                }
                ,
                s.m = i,
                s.c = t,
                s.d = function(e, r, t) {
                    s.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, {
                        enumerable: !0,
                        get: t
                    })
                }
                ,
                s.r = function(e) {
                    "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
                        value: "Module"
                    }),
                    Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
                        value: !0
                    })
                }
                ,
                s.t = function(r, e) {
                    if (1 & e && (r = s(r)),
                    8 & e)
                        return r;
                    if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule)
                        return r;
                    var t = Object.create(null);
                    if (s.r(t),
                    Object.defineProperty(t, "default", {
                        enumerable: !0,
                        value: r
                    }),
                    2 & e && "string" != typeof r)
                        for (var n in r)
                            s.d(t, n, function(e) {
                                return r[e]
                            }
                            .bind(null, n));
                    return t
                }
                ,
                s.n = function(e) {
                    var r = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
                        return e.default
                    }
                    : function() {
                        return e
                    }
                    ;
                    return s.d(r, "a", r),
                    r
                }
                ,
                s.o = function(e, r) {
                    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)
                }
                ,
                s.p = "/",
                s.oe = function(e) {
                    throw console.error(e),
                    e
                }
                ;
                var r = window["webpackJsonpgps-track"] = window["webpackJsonpgps-track"] || []
                  , n = r.push.bind(r);
                r.push = e,
                r = r.slice();
                for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++)
                    e(r[o]);
                var d = n;
                f()
            }([])
```

I tried different ways in order to solve this issue  I couldn't. I will be greateful if someone can help me with this.

All my code are available on my github
https://github.com/EstuardoValenzuela/gps-track-amplify-react

I tried to create a single app using the command (npx create-react-app my-app) and adding Amplify, just to check if the problem is only on Amplify, but I didn't recive any error, I think the routes that I'm using on my project can be a part of the error, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! In order to solve this issue I follow this steps:

**File: package.json**

Change the homepage key to:

```
 "homepage":  "/",
```

**The file where you are import Amplify, (in my case tablelist.jsx)**

Change

```
import Amplify, {API, graphqlOperation} from 'aws-amplify';
```

To:

```
import {Amplify, API, graphqlOperation} from 'aws-amplify';
```